# What is a general term to describe total units transferred?

Tags: networking, bandwidth, terminology

I've been seeing the term "bandwidth" abused in recent years, especially by telecommunications companies. People refer to transfer caps as "bandwidth caps", but bandwidth describes a rate not a capacity or "total bytes over time".

What is the correct term or phrase to describe the total number of units (bytes, megabytes, etc) transferred over time? For example, instead of saying "This carrier has a bandwidth cap", what would you say instead?

Comment: I would probably call them 'usage caps', as they do reflect the amount of data you've actually transferred, but without the time component that is inherent in any frequency-based metric like Mb/S. Some of the companies call this Consumption (like its a limited resource that can be permanently consumed), eg Consumption Based Billing.

Comment: Data usage or traffic, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a term that would be more/most accurate would be "transfer quota".

[Quota](https://www.google.ca/search?q=quota):

> a limited or fixed number or amount of people or things, in particular.

The Wikipedia "Bandwidth Cap" article [mentions it as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_cap#Download_quota) (specifically "Download quota"):

> A download quota is a restriction fixed by some ISPs (Internet Service Provider) to limit the volume of data downloaded by the end user during a fixed period, usually a month. Once a fixed download cap (e.g. 250 gigabytes/month) has been reached by the end user, the speed at which they access the internet is usually throttled to a slower speed, cut off, or they are charged for excess data usage.

Answer (score 0):

There is a catch to your question becasue bandwith is the anwser.

[Wikipedia example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_(computing)) look at the "Internet connection bandwidths" section you'll see that bandwith is "data units"/time.

Comment: A bandwidth cap would mean that they are limiting the speed of data transfer, not really the **total amount** of data that *may* be transferred. So it doesn't seem to be the answer.

Comment: Well the next article I looked at defined [Bandwodth cap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_cap) as "limits the transfer of a specified amount of data over a period of time". That is still inline iwth what I said. If I am still missunderstanding this then give me an example of a cap.

Comment: The cap the OP is speaking about has nothing to do with "over time". Consider 10KM/h (speed) vs. 10KM (distance). OP is interested in the term for a 'distance cap'. :)

Comment: @sgp667 I think that definition expresses the very violation that I talk about at the start of my post.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Ok thanks for the input, provided you and OP are thinking about the same thing I am missing something. I hope this doesn't sound like a snide remark, but once you take out the time from data/time then to my understanding user ceases to receive service permanentaly?? FIY I am not a networking expert of any sort

Comment: No problems. :)  Let's try this: If I gave you a car that could do a maximum speed of 200KM/h, and said "You can only drive 100KM in this car, total". In regards to what the OP is asking, its maximum _speed_, and _how fast_ you actually drive it, doesn't change the fact that you can only drive a total _distance_ of 100KM. Once you hit 100KM total distance travelled, you can't drive it anymore, at any speed. :)